# How to locally clean git directories which were removed by a commit, but contain ignored files?

Tags: git

Suppose that I work on a project which contains a module in a directory named `a`. My IDE creates some files per each module, so there is a file, say, `a/module.txt`, and `.gitignore` says that all `**/module.txt` files should be ignored.
But then someone else reorganizes that repository and deletes the directory `a` and pushes their commit. If I then `pull` that commit to my local copy, Git will keep the directory `a` in my filesystem, because it contains an ignored file (and only deletes those files in it which are NOT ignored). But I don't want that directory anymore and want to discard it including the ignored files.

So basically, how do I tell Git to discard directories which were removed by a pulled commit, but contain files which are covered by `.gitignore`?

At first I thought I could do `git clean -dfX` (to remove the ignored files) followed by `git clean -df` (to remove the leftover directories, because they themselves are not ignored), but that removes ALL ignored files, and I don't want to have to force my IDE to create them again.

Comment: All your talk about deleting or keeping a directory is wrong. You cannot say anything to git about _directories_. There are no directories in git. The person who deleted did not delete a directory (as far as git is concerned). They deleted some files. You pulled and those files had not been modified locally so they were deleted for you too. No problem. If you have other files you don’t want, delete them yourself.

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is to locally delete directories, that ONLY contain ignored files? I'm not aware of any git magic that will do that out of the box, but a custom script could help?

Comment: @matt Someone removed a whole directory (or all files within it, if you prefer to put it this way) and I want to remove it locally too, because it's trash now. Deleting the leftover directories manually is not very practical, because the project actually consists of hundreds of modules, and they change quite rapidly.

Comment: @matt I understood this as a local cleanup operation rather than trying to do anything to the repository itself. I imagine this can be annoying if it constantly happens and nothing you want to do by hand all the time.

Comment: @JanMartiška add what operating system/ command line environment you're using. I don't think there's a git only solution to this, other than the one you posted yourself.

Comment: Yes I agree. If you know the rule for what files git is ignoring, you know the rule for deleting them thru a script. But that is not a git matter.

Comment: @v01pe Linux and bash. I think I will need to write a custom shell script for that, I just wanted to ask first, because it seems weird to me that Git can't handle such (in my opinion) basic scenario.

Comment: Had a similar issue once and ended up writing a custom script… I guess `git clean -df ` is the closest generic solution that you can get. E.g. I would not want to delete my `build/` directory, that also contains only ignored files, etc.